# Stop page from being remember in history after redirect

Tags: php, html, user-experience

I have a page which when an a link is clicked (which must remain an a link, with no JavaScript), is redirected to a PHP script to perform a near instantaneous operation, and then sent back to the previous page.

The problem is, when the user clicks the back button, the page goes back to the page that had been loaded before the script was performed, and the user has to click the back button twice before they can get back to the sending page.

Is there any way to stop this? It isn't a nice user experience having to click the back arrow twice, and there must be a (relatively easy) way to stop this from happening.

Any help appreciated.

this is the url for the site
http://pla-za.tk/php-login/like.php

This is the product_details.php code

```
<?php

////////////////database connection///////////////////////////////////////////
$con=mysqli_connect("*******","********","******","*********");
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$id=$_GET["id"];

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ilike FROM mothar WHERE product_id like $id");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
    $like_img="unlike.png";
}
else{
    $like_img ="like.png";
}

///////////////////////////////like query//////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id like $id");
echo "<table border='2'>
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>button</td>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
      $product_id=$row['id'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
  echo "<td><form action='test4.php' method='post' name'idnumber'><input type='submit' name='like' value='$product_id' style='background-image:url(http://pla-za.tk/php-login/images/$like_img); width:50px; height:35px; color:transparent; display:block; border:0px;'/></form></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

$product_likes= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT likes FROM products WHERE id like $id");

while($rowlike=mysqli_fetch_array($product_likes))
{
    $like =$rowlike['likes'];

}

?>
<?php echo "$like like this" ;

?>
```

and this code for test4.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("*********","********","********","********");
  $like_submit= $_POST["like"];
$product_likes= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT likes FROM products WHERE id like $like_submit");

while($rowlike=mysqli_fetch_array($product_likes))
{
    $like =$rowlike['likes'];
}

//////////////////////////check if user put like //////////////////////////////
$check_query= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ilike FROM mothar WHERE product_id like $like_submit");
while($rowlike=mysqli_fetch_array($check_query))
{
    $ilike =$rowlike["ilike"];
}
///////////////////////////////if else(like)//////////////////////////////////
if (mysqli_num_rows($check_query) >0){

    //////////////////////////delete 1 like from products table/////////////////////
$add_like_to_products_table=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE products SET likes= $like-1
WHERE id like $like_submit");

$delete_like_in_user_table =mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM mothar WHERE product_id like $like_submit");


}
else{
    //////////////////////////add 1 like to products table//////////////////////////
    $add_like_to_products_table=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE products SET likes=$like+1
WHERE id like $like_submit");

$add_like_in_user_table =mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO mothar (product_id, ilike)
VALUES ($like_submit, 1)");


}
////////////////////////////////////
header( "Location: http://pla-za.tk/php-login/product_details.php?id=1" );
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you need an AJAX call

Comment: "and then sent back to the previous page." how? Provide code.

Comment: Not clicking that... how would I see the php code anyway?  It should go in the question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I can give you 2 options

1. Use AJAX call. This way you stay on the same page but the request to the server is made.
2. Place the code from that other script into the script of the fist page. You can use GET value in url like `script.php?specialAction=true`. That way you don't need to jump from one page to another but you just load the same page again with an argument that says that some special action should be performed. Obviously you need to put something like this into the code

   ```
   if($_GET['specialAction']) {
        // do something cool here
   }
   ```

Comment: if you need me to look at your code, you can put it on http://pastebin.com and copy link here

Comment: yeah, that's true, you should have included the code in the question in the first place... please do it now and always in the future

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code you're using I'm just really guessing but I do know this:  using any kind of meta refresh method will put interim pages into your client's browser history, but if you use

```
header("Location: destination.php");
```

It will not.